# Are all linear transformations measurable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convexity

Let $V$ and $W$ be topological vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ (with $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation. It is well-known that $T$ is not necessarily continuous. But is $T$ necessarily measurable (with respect to the Borel structures of $V$ and $W$)? Does the answer change when we specifically consider $W=\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: This fails for even finite-dimensional spaces. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359183/measurable-cauchy-function-is-continuous Or even better yet, see this: http://artsci.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~ssaito/eng/maths/Cauchy.pdf

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Thank you for your reply - but in the context of vector spaces, when I say "linear transformation", I mean a transformation that preserves _both_ addition _and_ scalar multiplication.

Comment: Oh, of course you're right -- my apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is answered by the well-known construction of a non-continuous linear form on an infinite dimensional Banach space using Hamel bases. Note also  that there is a measurable graph theorem (L. Schwartz) which implies that all measurable linear maps, say between separable Banach spaces, are continuous. And there are models of set theory in which ALL linear mappings between suitable classes of spaces are continuous (Solovay and Garnir).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry, I'm probably being a bit dim: how do you prove that the standard example of a discontinuous linear form on an infinite-dimensional Banach space is non-measurable?

Comment: This follows by standard arguments from the fact that it is unbounded on any ball.

Comment: I understand that the point of the example is that it is unbounded on any ball - but I do not know what the "standard arguments" are by which one can deduce non-measurability. (I presume you must be using completeness of the Banach space somehow, since on a countable-dimensional normed vector space the same construction gives a map that is unbounded on every ball and yet is measurable.)

Comment: Baire's category theorem (cover the Banach space by the sets where $|f|\leq n$).  By the way, it is not customary for questons of this sort to be answered in MO to the last detsil so this is my final word.

Comment: Generalization (automatic continuity)... For a homomorphism between complete separable metric groups, if it has the property of Baire, then it is continuous.  (In particular, Borel-Borel measurable maps have the property of Baire.)

Comment: Interesting, thanks - is the proof straightforward?